# How to write a single SQL query to display grades?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have a table with test scores and want to write a single SQL query to display grades

```
F for scores below 35, 
D for scores 36-50, 
C for scores 51-60, 
B for 61-75, 
A for 76-85, 
A* for 85+,
```

how should I do it using sqlite3 in linux terminal.

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `CASE` statements

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: `.dump`please. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-quer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

It may be help you

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN SCORES < 35 THEN 'F' 
        WHEN SCORES BETWEEN 36 AND 50 THEN 'D' 
        WHEN SCORES BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN 'C' 
        WHEN SCORES BETWEEN 61 AND 75 THEN 'B' 
        WHEN SCORES BETWEEN 76 AND 85 THEN 'A'
        WHEN SCORES > 85 THEN 'A+'
        END AS GRADE
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```